# No encuentro mi app publica en la Play Store

Tags: android, android-studio, app, google-play

Recientemente realice la publicación de mi aplicación en la play store, pero cuando realizo la búsqueda no lo encuentro por ningún lado, cuando lo busco con el nombre del paquete de creación de Android studio recien aparece, o como podría modificarlo para que la búsqueda en la play store de como resultado mi app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la publicación es una nueva app que subí un el día de ayer con el titulo de RADIO STREAMING, en mi android studio el nombre de paquete lleva "com.proyectoradio.radio"  la play console me informa que ya esta publicada, pero cuando me dirijo a la play y busco "RADIO STREAMING" no me aparece mi app, pero si coloco "proyectoradio" me aparece mi aplicación y como es la primera aplicacion que publico no logro encontrar cual es el problema, para que los usuarios al colocar radio streaming logren ver mi app o por lo menos aparezca en la lista de app

ya realice las busqueda y consultas a compañeros para que realizen la busqueda
cuando escribo el titulo de mi app nada
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si escribo el nombre de paquete si aparece

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Descarga la app "Play Console", me late que tu app está siendo revisada, toma algunos días :)

Comment: Suele tardar unas horas en actualizar la información.

Comment: @DiegoAlameda Agrega más información, ¿es nueva o actualización?, ¿ Cual es el paquete de tu app?

Comment: @DiegoAlameda el paquete que mencionas "com.proyectoradio.radio" no corresponde con la imagen, ¿es otra app?

Comment: no, la aplicación subida y con la que tengo el problema es esa solo que coloque los nombres en la pregunta con la finalidad de que sea mas entendible.

Comment: @DiegoAlameda tu aplicación ya esta visible, en este caso tu aplicación Google Play debe tener caché por esa razón aún no aparece, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: @DiegoAlameda acabo de ver la edición a tu pregunta, cambia la categoría de tu app, revisa mi respuesta, recuerda que las aplicaciones deben estar valoradas para mostrarse en el listado principal, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

El paquete de tu aplicación es

```
com.marslnlau.radio
```

por lo tanto tu aplicación se puede encontrar en la Google Play  accediendo a el enlace:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marslnlau.radio

La aplicación debe mostrarse en los dispositivos, la liberación para todos los usuarios puede tardar algunas horas.

Para asegurar esto revisa la consola Google Play en "Release Management", asegura que tenga dispositivos soportados tu aplicación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es importante comentar que si tratas de instalarla desde la aplicación Google Play de un dispositivo Android, esta en ocasiones guarda caché por lo que puedes eliminarla de la aplicación Google Play y volver a realizar la búsqueda.

---

**Si esta publicada pero esta no se muestra al buscar "Radio Bolivia Joven" es porque tu app tiene definida una categoría que no es propia para aplicaciones de radio, tienes `Entertainment`**.

**Debes definir la categoría: `Music & Audio`** (Musica y audio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda también que las aplicaciones deben estar valoradas para mostrarse en el listado principal, tu app actualmente tiene una valoración y una instalación.

Answer (score 0):

Hola grupo quiero finalizar la pregunta, envie un mensaje con la duda a soporte de Play Store el cual el cual me informa que cuando el titulo de una nueva APP lleva tiempo que se indexe para la busqueda en la Play Store ademas el motor de busqueda solo muestra aquellas aplicaciones que tienen instalaciones en celulares con la sugerencia de utilizar su servicio de publicidad para hacer mas publico mi aplicacion en los canales de google, en mi caso hice que varios de mis usuarios locales se instalen la aplicacion y pasado 3 dias ya puedo encontrar mi aplicación en la lista de la play store por su titulo solo que muy abajo.

Answer (score 0):

Es Debido al algoritmo de la store, tu app tardara unos dias en estar entre los primeros de la lista. Si la gente la descarga es mejor para que se posicione mas rapido. Solo tienes que esperar.